# Design UIScrollView in Interface Builder using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

How can I design an `UIScrollView` in Interface Builder without setting the root view's size to `Freeform`?

I want to be able to view the content that's outside the screen and still be able to `View as` other devices.

Comment: Can you explain question with example.

Comment: You need such flexibility while designing you layout correct?

Comment: @AshwinIndianic, Yes

Comment: @agent_stack, I don't know how to explain it better. I want the root view's size to be `Inferred` to be able to preview it on different screen sizes, but also see the views that are outside the scroll view's bounds.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Yeah you can do it.

Comment: @agent_stack, How?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Just for confirmation , you wanted a scrollview from storyboard & you don't wanted to give it freedom frame and also wanted to see all the contents inside it with the help of scrolling property. I just repeated your ques so i am getting you right or not?

Comment: @agent_stack, If possible, `.xib` file, if not, it's ok to use a storyboard too. Yes, you got it right.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You cannot do it from storyboard but you can scroll any way from the running project. once I thought you are talking about at run time but I re-read your query and tried here. It is can't possible buddy. But you can do it same thing with tableView and collectionView.